# SQL find distinct and show other columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have read many replies and to similar questions but cannot seem to apply it to my situation.  I have a table that averages 10,000 records and is ever changing. It containing a column called `deviceID` which has about 20 unique values, another called `dateAndTime` and many others including `status1` and `status2`. I need to isolate one instance each deviceID, showing the record that had the most current dateAndTime. This works great using:

```
select DISTINCT deviceID, MAX(dateAndTime)
from MyTable 
Group By deviceID 
ORDER BY MAX(dateAndTime) DESC
```

(I have noticed omitting **DISTINCT** from the above statement also yields the same result)

However, I cannot expand this statement to include the fields status fields without incurring errors in the statement or incorrect results. I have tried using **IN** and **EXISTS** and syntax to isolate rows, all without luck. I am wondering how I can nest or re-write this query so that the results will display the unique deviceID's, the date of the most recent record and the corresponding `status` fields associated with those unique records.

Comment: Please state your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the DeviceID + DateAndTime is UNIQUE you can do the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    MyTable as T1, 
    (SELECT DeviceID, max(DateAndTime) as mx FROM MyTable group by DeviceID) as T2 
WHERE 
    T1.DeviceID  = T2.DeviceID AND 
    T1.DateAndTime = T2.mx
```

So basically what happens is, that you do a group by on the DeviceID (NOTE: A GROUP BY always goes with an aggregate function. We are using MAX in this case).
Then you join the Query with the Table, and add the DeviceID + DateAndTime in the WHERE clause.

Side Note... GROUP BY will return distinct elements with or without adding DISTINCT because all rows are distinct by default.

Comment: In my case, I think the two fields will always be unique, so this plus `order by dateAndTime desc` tacked on at the end produces exactly what I need.  Thanks!  I assume that if there were a case that a non-unique case between deviceID and max(dateAndTime), this would display all of those rows?  (or would it still show one row, but just selecting one out of the non-unique choices?)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM( SELECT DISTINCT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deviceID ORDER BY dateAndTime DESC) as rown
      FROM MyTable ) a
WHERE a.rown = 1
```

Comment: This is also producing the desired result with `order by dateAndTime desc` added after it.  I notice this is a shorter solution - does it offer better performance?  Thanks!